# Error al recuperar el nombre de la hoja inmediatamente anterior

Tags: excel

Intento recuperar el valor que está en una celda de la hoja **justo anterior a la hoja en que me encuentro**, es decir, desde la que quiero lanzar el código. Porque , el nombre de la hoja justo anterior, puede ser distinto, según en qué libro de excel me encuentre para lanzar este código.
Me da error de que el calificador debe ser una colección, como si no me reconociera la variable que tenía que recuperar el nombre de dicha página anterior. El error me lo marca en el signo de exclamación.

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim nombrehojaanterior As String
  nombrehojaanterior = Workbook.Worksheets.Previous.Name
  Range("B1").Value = nombrehojaanterior!H2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Ese código VBA no es correcto. Previus.Name no existe, al igual que cuando intentas asignar a B2 el nombre de la hoja poniendo !H2...

Prueba esto:

```
Sub Macro1()

  Dim nombrehojaanterior As String
  Dim hoja_actual As Worksheet
  Dim Total_Hojas As Integer

  Set hoja_actual = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pepe")
  Total_Hojas = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

  For i = 1 To Total_Hojas

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = hoja_actual.Name And i <> 1 Then
        nombrehojaanterior = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i - 1).Name
        Range("B1").Value = nombrehojaanterior
    ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = hoja_actual.Name And i = 1 Then
        Range("B1").Value = "La primera hoja es Pepe"
    End If

  Next i

End Sub
```

Con esto la hoja desde la que compruebas el nombre de la hoja anterior se llama Pepe. 
Recorres todas las hojas del libro hasta llegar a la que te interesa, si el nombre de la hoja coincide resta uno a la variable del contador de hojas y te devuelve su nombre en B1.

Comment: Deberías añadir algo para evitar errores. Supongamos que la hoja PEPE fuera justo la primera, con lo cual i=1 y daría error porque no hay hoja con index 0. Pero tu desarrollo es el correcto.